# Firebird performance: Update/Select verus Insert/Select last

Tags: performance, firebird

I have to keep an account balance up to date, a log of changes,  and to use it.

It seems to me that the options are to either:

1. keep it in a single row,
2. use a trigger to save changes to a separate table
3. use an select|update to do the update
4. use a simple select from the table to access the value

The alternative is:

1. Keep the value in a separate table,
2. Use Select Last and Insert to effect the update
3. Use Select Last from the separate table to access the value

Does anyone know which is faster? Is there much in it?

Steve

Comment: I think your question needs more detail, because as it stands I think it is too vague. For example: I have no idea what you mean with "use an select|update to do the update" or what a "Select Last" means.

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing seems far too complicated...
I would sugest to do a different thing:
I would have two tables with a master-detail relation.
In the detail I would insert rows and its triggers would update the master table

```
balance (account, amount, ...)
balance_detail (account, amount, ...)

balance_detail_after_insert
begin
    update master
    set amount = amount + new.amount
    where account = new.account;
end

balance_detail_after_update
begin
    update master
    set amount = amount + new.amount - old.amount
    where account = new.account;
end

balance_detail_after_delete
begin
    update master
    set amount = amount - new.amount
    where account = new.account;
end
```

After any change you should simply close/open the master table to refresh data.